# No GitHub Actions logs show when pushing code to a private Repo

Tags: github, logging, github-actions, private-repository

I am a member of a private GitHub Repo and have got all 'Read' and 'Write' permissions. I am able to push code and everything but the problem is GitHub Actions shows no logs whatsoever.

Below is my yml file -

```
name: Run Karate tests (Maven)
on:
  push:
    branch: main
jobs:
  karate-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven

    - name: Enable Debug Mode
      run: |
        echo "ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Initialize Database
      run: |
        psql -U prag-sri -d ${{ secrets.DB }} -a -f path/to/setup_script.sql

    - name: Karate tests
      working-directory: src/test/java
      env:
        HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        DB: ${{ secrets.DB }}
        PASS: ${{ secrets.PASS }}
      run: ./run-tests.sh

    - name: Print Message
      run: |
        echo "This is a custom message to the logs."

    - name: Teardown Database
      run: |
        psql -U prag-sri -d ${{ secrets.DB }} -a -f path/to/teardown_script.sql

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: Karate Report
        path: target/customReport
```

I tried 'echo "This is a custom message to the logs."' but nothing shows.
I have also set environment variables : 'ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG' and 'ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG' as true.

This is what is shown:
[image]